# How to solve "Cannot read property 'replace' of null" for Karma testing with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am using Karma and jasmine for the unit testing for UI. I set-up all required dependencies. when I start the debug to the test case is failing and giving

> Cannot read property 'replace' of null

Warning giving in the debug.js, But I am not using any debug.js file.

screen shot:

[image]

**package.js**

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a tool to aid",
  "main": "index.html",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "gulp dev",
    "prod": "gulp prod"
  },
  "author": "kim",
  "license": "Myange Inc.",
  "devDependencies": {
    "event-stream": "~3.3.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.7.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-maven-deploy": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "gulp-zip": "^4.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.1.0",
    "karma": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.0.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.7.2"
  }
}
```

**UnitTestCase.js**

```
describe('app.way-bus of test ', function() {
  // beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));
  var $controller, $rootScope;
  var DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder, $http, $q, $compile, Notifier, $location, $sce, $filter, FRh, Rh, RhAuth, $stateParams, $state;
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('restheart'));
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app.cargo-watchListMgmt', function($provide) {
    mockedFactory = {
      save: jasmine.createSpy()
    };
    Notifier = $provide.value('Notifier', mockedFactory);
  }));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_,_Rh_,_$stateParams_,_$state_,_Notifier_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    console.log($rootScope)

    Rh = _Rh_;
    //RhAuth = _RhAuth_;
    $stateParams = _$stateParams_;
    $state = _$state_;
    Notifier = _Notifier_;
  }));

  describe('call fetchData', function() {
    it('check', function() {
      var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      console.log($scope)
      var controller = $controller('wayBusCntrl', {

        $scope: $scope,

        Rh: Rh,
        //RhAuth: RhAuth,
        $stateParams: $stateParams,
        $state: $state,
        Notifier: Notifier
      });

      expect($scope.xyz).toBe('satya')
    });
  });


});
```

So I am not able to process my unit testing because of that error(Cannot read property 'replace' of null).

Comment: The problem is on your test: `app.cargo-watchListMgmt`. Please post this one

Comment: @PlayMa256 Actually I changed in the posted code for some reason. Now I updated..But problem is the same